# How to interact with plotly.figure_factory hover?

Tags: python, hover, plotly, mapbox, figure

I tried the following code:

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px


df = px.data.carshare()

fig = go.Figure() 


app = dash.Dash()
#fac figurile
fig  = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(df,lat = 'centroid_lat', lon = 'centroid_lon',nx_hexagon = 10,color = 'car_hours',
                               labels = {'color':'Point Count '},

                               opacity = 0.5)


fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter")
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(b=0, t=0, l=0, r=0))

fig.show()
```

And it displays:
[image]

And I want to modify the hover so that it will only show me the float value with only the first decimal on hover and I also want to be able to display something after it displays the value. For example the value on the hover should be 'Point Count = 1019.9 cars per hour. Unfortunately, the documentation does not help very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your best option for [`ff.create_hexbin_mapbox`](https://plotly.com/python/hexbin-mapbox/) would be to configure it directly through:

```
fig.data[0].hovertemplate = 'Point Count =%{z:,.1f}<extra>Cars per hour</extra>'
```

Which will turn this:

[image]

... into this:

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px


df = px.data.carshare()

fig = go.Figure() 


# app = dash.Dash()
#fac figurile
fig  = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(df,lat = 'centroid_lat', lon = 'centroid_lon',nx_hexagon = 10,color = 'car_hours',
                               labels = {'color':'Point Count '},

                               opacity = 0.5)


fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter")
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(b=0, t=0, l=0, r=0))
fig.data[0].hovertemplate = 'Point Count =%{z:,.1f}<extra>Cars per hour</extra>'
fig.show()
```